# How can I get the information table and image aligned on the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a web-page where I have a table of information and an image side-by-side as in the example below

Example:

```
 bar fOo
```

Instead of:

```
bar
fOo
```

I have placed the image within a div and the information table in another div element, and I have been playing with the CSS properties to try to get them to be side-by-side, however they refuse to work as expected.

The CSS is below, #book is the image itself, while book_information is the information inside the table.

```
    #book
    {
        float: right;
        flex: 33.33%;
        padding: 5px;
        margin-left: 0;
        width: 50%;
    
    }
    
    #book_information
    {
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
        padding-right: 0;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
    
    
    table
    {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        float:top;
        border: 1px solid black;
        table-layout: fixed;
        width: 50%;
    }
```

What should I use to allow this to work as expected? and what improvements could work I work on to get it responsive?

Below is the html structure of the page at the moment that I am using along with this:

```
    <main>
    
                <div>
                    <div class= "left" id="book"><img src="Book.jpg" alt="></div>
                    <div class="left" id="book_information">
                        <table id="information">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="1">Price:</td>
                                <td class="1">€18.90</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Author</td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="1">About</td>
                                <td class="1"><p></p></td>
                            </tr>
    
                            <tr>
                                <td>Where to get it:</td>
                                <td><a href="">Amazon</a> ,
                                <a href="">Casa Del Libro</a> ,
                                <a href="">FNAC</a> ,
                                <a href="">Libelista</a>
                                </td>
    
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
```

Comment: Can you add the HTML? that would help addressing your issue.

Comment: Done theres the html associated with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways of doing this.

Here's a solution that involves using `float:left` style for your table:

```css
table {
  float: left;
}

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>$5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Author</td>
    <td>Bob</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div>
  <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.png?text=Book+Image"
      alt="Book Image Here">
</div>
```

This one involves putting your table and image in yet another table:

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Price</td>
          <td>$5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Author</td>
          <td>Bob</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <img
            src="https://via.placeholder.com/120.png?text=Book+Image"
            alt="Book Image Here">
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you man it has worked, i used the within a table method, was easiest to manipulate

Comment: glad to hear it! please mark as answer if it was the right solution